# Perform sumproduct in PowerBI using 2 fact tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, dimensional-modeling

I need to perform sumproduct in powerBI using 2 fact tables.

Below is the tables relationship of my model

[image: Tables relationship]

What I need to do is perform a sumproduct between the highlighted fields.

on table `dw fact qnt cotas` I have a value in `Quantidade_total` for each agregatted fields `Ativo`, `CPF/CNPF`, `DataCorrigida`

And i need to relate those information with table `API Quantum` which has a value in field `Provento Dividendos não Ajustado` for each `Codigo` (same as `ativo` in previous table) and `Data` (same as `DataCorrigida` in previous table).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: is there an equivalent of `CPF/CNPF` in `API Quantum`? If not how should `Quantidade_total` be aggregated if it can only be matched with `Provento Dividendos não Ajustado` on Date&Ativo?

Comment: @Stachu
No, there is no equivalent of CPF/CNPJ in API Quantum.

I need to relate each row on "dw fact qnt" cotas with its proper "Provento Dividendos não Ajustado". 

There is a selection on my dashboard that will identify a unique "CPF/CNPJ" and from this selection I need to return the sumproduct of "Quantidade_total" and "Provento Dividendos não Ajustado" using "Ativo" and "Date" to relate them